# Mp3 sound is delayed on phone (iphone 7) - Blazor WASM + javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have blazor WASM app with "correct" .mp3 file that is played via javascript code. On the Desktop lets say its pretty instant after pressing button but on the phone its skips few ms and then it seems there is delay and its not good user experience. I tried to look up some solutions but couldnt find anything. Is there any way to solve it or its just because of phone (Iphone 7)?

sounds.js:

```
window.PlayAudio = (elementName) => {
    document.getElementById(elementName).play();
}
```

*.razor:

```
<audio id="sound" src="@navManager.BaseUri/sound/correct.mp3" />
<button id="soundButton" @onclick="PlaySound">Click me to play "correct" sound</button>
...
    public async Task PlaySound()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("PlayAudio", "sound");
    }
```

Please see the repo and webapp:

https://github.com/Laftek/BlazorWASMPWAStaticPublish

https://laftek.github.io/BlazorWASMPWAStaticPublish/Lottie/7

Thank you any help would be much apprieciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Blazor issue-- it's a client browser behavior.  It was once the standard across all devices, but I think newer devices have dropped some of the restrictions as audio files are no longer considered "large files."

Getting consistent media playback across all platforms has always been EXTREMELY difficult-- especially apple products, and most especially older apple products.  I suspect that the sound will not start loading at all until a user action (like a button click).  Then, unless you have fast data transfer, it will take some time to buffer.  This was a common security feature for mobile devices to prevent sites from wasting users' data with media they didn't want.

The solution is to catch a click early on in the site's progress-- usually with a loading screen and "click here to enter."  Then IN THAT CLICK HANDLER (important) you pre-start all your audio files by playing them and immediately pausing them again.  Now, they will (probably) load, and when you really want to play the file, it will be loaded and ready.

**Note that a simulated click will not work, so you can't just do `element.onclick()` after the page renders.  It has to be an actual user interaction.**

Javascript audio elements have various events, like `canplay` which let you know when enough of an audio source is loaded that you can start playing it.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

If you're lucky, Blazor has exposed the `oncanplay` event.  Then you can use that even to enable your plaback button.  I don't know if they have got around to audio events yet or not.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for replying that late. I tried all options you proposed but it didnt really help in practice (in theory it should work). After some playing I found load() attribute that helped but also I have to create new instance of audio after every "render" because on mobile only first visit it plays whole sound. So combination load() and creating new js instance (and ten disposing) solved my issue. Thank you for your explanation it helped me to think of it other ways.

Comment: I just found out its consuming memory like crazy so I need to deal with this.

Comment: I don't think so.  Your browser will load your file-- and then play it.  That's it.  Even a 10 year-old phone will easily have enough memory for this.  If you are having problems with memory, you're doing something goofy, like trying to preload 100 songs or something.